# Hide header and footer in panel yii2

Tags: yii2

How to hide header and footer in view of yii2?

```
view->panel
```

One page without header and footer in yii2.

```
<div class="wrap">
</div>
```

and

```
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
```

Comment: You can create a separate layout without header and footer and use that wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app/views/layout you can create a layouts without header  and footer  (eg: starting duplicating main.php layout and removing what not needed)

then in you controller/action  you can use the new layout assigning

```
   ... 
   $this->layout = 'your_new_layout';
   return $this->render('your_view',[
      'model'=> $model,
   ]);
```